# How to debug emberjs computed property

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a computed property that depends on other properties. How can I find out which change on dependency property triggers re-compute on my property. Other than that, is there any way to debug computed chaining?

Comment: i guess there is no easy way, you may need to use computed property with getter and setter, and compare with your previous values

Comment: i look at the source code in order to see if there are any undocumented features we can benefit from; but no luck. may be you can ask at ember discuss and someone from the core team should give an appropriate answer. i believe you have no chance but to rely on observers instead of computed property to learn about changing properties. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check that property is trigger by `notifyPropertyChange()` method. You can use `notifyPropertyChange()` method to trigger the computed property.

Comment: For a good while `notifyPropertyChange` was considered private API. I wouldn't encourage its usage. It is a smell; its usage usually means that the code needs to be refactored.

Also, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your computed properties are in a component, you can try hooking into the `didUpdateAttrs` hook. `didUpdateAttrs` fire when values which were passed into the component update. Within the didUpdateAttrs you can check to see what attrs were changed by comparing the old/new values.

```
  didUpdateAttrs: function(attrs) {
    // attrs should have access to the old/new values

  }
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/

> didUpdateAttrs runs when the attributes of a component have changed,
>   but not when the component is re-rendered, via component.rerender,
>   component.set, or changes in models or services used by the template.
>
> A didUpdateAttrs is called prior to rerender, you can use this hook to
>   execute code when specific attributes are changed. This hook can be an
>   effective alternative to an observer, as it will run prior to a
>   re-render, but after an attribute has changed.
>
> An example of this scenario in action is a profile editor component.
>   As you are editing one user, and the user attribute is changed, you
>   can use didUpdateAttrs to clear any error state that was built up from
>   editing the previous user.

Comment: Just note using `attrs` in life cycle hook method is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `LOG_BINDINGS` can show you what you need.
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/configuring-ember/debugging/#toc_log-object-bindings

What I would do is [set breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#loc) in the computeds that are being depended on.